# Client / Server C Connection

Tags: c, client-server

I am currently doing a client / server application in C that words over the internet.The server is to keep listening for new connections from the clients. Currently I am listening to cllients, but once a client connects, the server wont keep on listening for further clients. The following depicts the server side code to connect with a client:

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in sockaddr, cliaddr;
bzero(&sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
bzero(&cliaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sockaddr.sin_port = ntohs(atoi(argv[1]));

if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) <0) {
    printf("error binding socket: %d\n", errno);
    exit(1);
}

printf("binded to %d : %d\n", sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, htons(sockaddr.sin_port));

listen(sockfd,5);
socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
int newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR on accept");

printf("server connected to %d:%d\n", cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, htons(cliaddr.sin_port));
```

I am assuming i have to create some form of threads that will fork once a connection has been established. But i dont know how to implement it..

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Following points might help:

1. You should have your accept call in a loop, so that after accepting one connection, it can go back again to accept more connections.
2. To process each of the connections seperately, you can create threads using [pthread_create or some similar thread creation APIs](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).
3. You can choose to use [Non-Blocking sockets](http://rhoden.id.au/doc/sockets.html) using which you can process multiple-connections in the same thread easily.

Comment: thanks for your reply... will look up more on the following points you pointed out

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the following Book to learn and understand how to develop concurrent server in C. It is hard to explain with examples various ways of writing concurrent server in the answer. The source codes of the examples in the book are downloadable so you can try them out even without the book (you will find in the same URL). Study the code and you will see how things work.

[UNIX Network Programming, Volume 1, Second Edition: Networking APIs: Sockets and XTI](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html)

This book covers almost all the things you want to know about socket programming.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need to discuss stuffs related to UNIX system/network programming you can ping me in mrayub@gmail.com. I learnt network programming from the mentioned book and now I have good knowledge in network programming and currently I am writing a Web Server for some specific needs of my projects. I can help you with ideas if possible.